# Create a Machine learning model with Keras using the openCV created dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, coreml

I have created a dataset for face recognition using openCV + python. I would like to create a model using this dataset in Keras.
Is it possible?

Comment: Yes You must use cv::ml there are some methods and algorithms for that like gabor,PCA,SVM,DNN,KNN,MLP

Comment: Maybe you can find a clue here: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html